# How can I solve NetBeans plugin dependencies (user and not developer question)?

Tags: netbeans

Within the context of upgrading plugins explain how to resolve plugin dependencies when NetBeans user interface's reports specific missing dependencies, yet these do not resolve with a google search or are unmentioned in the netbeans FAQ.

The practical example leading me to ask this question was when I attempted to install an in-development-plugin [*org-netbeans-modules-htmlprojects.nbm*](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199889). It requires **[General Queries API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-queries/overview-summary.html)** *v1.24* and I have *v1.19.1*.

Comment: What version of Netbeans or you using?  That plugin lives in the experimental update center, so certain compatibility issues may be expected....

Comment: Fedora 15, NetBeans 6.9.1, JDK 1.6u27

Comment: I have this exact question myself. Would be nice if it had been answered. v7.2, click a plugin, then Install, and you get a list of issues with the Next button disabled. Which one is stopping the auto-install of dependencies? We don't know. How do we update the individual plugins cited? We don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the bug report that mentions the nbm, it's for version 7.  This also means that the mentioned version for GQA is also version 7 specific.

You best choice is probably to upgrade to version 7, it has some nice improvements over version 6.9 like HTML5 support.  As a new install picks up the configuration of an installed previous version upgrading shouldn't be a lot of work.

EDIT based on restated question:

The short form: you cannot, it's not meant to work that way.

The long form: due to what happened here and the inner workings of Netbeans the error message was less clear than it could have been...

- you downloaded a module for a higher version than the installed one
- Netbeans' nbm deployment descriptor states dependencies on editor modules, not on editor versions - see inside the nbm which is actually a ZIP file `Info/info.xml`, `manifest` element, `OpenIDE-Module-Module-Dependencies` attribute.

Normally that error would not happen, as the version of the nbm will normally match the editor version, and the dependencies should either be satisfied or satisfiable by on-the-fly installation of the missing dependencies.

Comment: @ fvu, I'm sorry that my original question gave you the impression I wanted to know how to install this plugin. I'm still getting used to the SE format for posting questions. I rewrote the question. And based on this your very sensible recommendation to upgrade to 7 is still sensible, but not what I'm looking to understand...

Comment: Then the General Queris API is part of NetBeans or Java applications? And, I'm not meant to tinker under the hood as the error message suggests? That's confusing. (>_<)

Comment: GQA is a part of the Netbeans platform.  And hey, **you** provoked it to give such a confusing error message :-)

Comment: Subverting the grand scheme of NetBeans installing an agent provocateur. haha